# Como realizar o cálculo de amplitude móvel em listas?

Tags: python, lista

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou precisando criar uma função/loop/etc onde ela pega um valor de uma lista (n tamanho) e calcula os elementos seguindo a seguinte formula matemática:

`Y = |Xi-(Xi-1)|`

ou seja, se eu tenho uma lista com os seguintes valores `L = [1,2,3,4,5]` ela deverá realizar o seguinte calculo:

```
1
2-1
3-2
4-3
5-4
```

e salvar o resultado da operação em uma segunda lista. A equação matemática citada é o cálculo de amplitude móvel...

Estou tentando desse jeito por meio de um  `laço for`:

```
empty_list = [0]

for i in m_r_list[1:]:
  empty_list += i
```

**m_r_list**  é uma lista contendo **n** valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos quebrar a lógica necessária para resolver o seu problema nos seguintes passos:

- inicialize uma lista de saída (começa vazia);
- itere sobre os valores da lista de entrada;
- na primeira iteração, coloque o próprio valor da lista de entrada na lista de saída;
- nas demais iterações, calcule o valor resultante e coloque na lista de saída;
- ao final da iteração, a lista de saída estará da forma desejada.

O processo de colocar valores dentro de uma lista é feita com o método `list.append`.

Aqui está um loop que resolve seu problema (troquei os valores de entrada apenas para confirmar o funcionamento do código, já que seu exemplo de lista resultaria em `[1, 1, 1, ...]`):

```
lista = [1, 2, 2, 6, 1]
lista_saida = []

for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
    if i == 0:  
        # primeira entrada da lista, 
        # apenas repetimos o valor da
        # lista original na lista de saída
        lista_saida.append(valor)
    else:  
        # demais entradas da lista, 
        # calculamos o valor resultante 
        # e colocamos na lista de saída
        novo_valor = valor - lista[i-1]
        lista_saida.append(novo_valor)

print(lista_saida)
# output: [1, 1, 0, 4, -5]
```

Usei a [função `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar ao mesmo tempo sobre índices e valores da lista de entrada. Isso não é estritamente necessário, mas simplifica um pouco as coisas, pois a cada iteração precisaremos tanto dos valores (para realizar o cálculo) quanto dos índices (para acessar o elemento da iteração anterior, de índice `i-1`).

Se você não tiver restrições a usar bibliotecas externas, a [biblioteca `numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html) (muito utilizada para trabalhar com vetores e álgebra linear) oferece a [função `roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) que ajuda a fazer esse tipo de operação - ela "desliza" todos os elementos de uma sequência por um certo valor de *shift*. Aí é só fazer a subtração entre vetores e recuperar o primeiro elemento da sequência original:

```
import numpy as np

entrada = np.array([1, 2, 2, 6, 1])
print(np.roll(entrada, 1))
# output: [1 1 2 2 6]  
# note que os elementos foram "deslizados" 
# uma casa para a direita, com o último elemento
# dando a volta e aparecendo na primeira casa

saida = entrada - np.roll(entrada, 1)  # subtração de vetores
saida[0] = entrada[0]  # copiamos a primeira entrada para a saída
print(saida)
# output: [ 1  1  0  4 -5]
```

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada e testar aqui, obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: Eu teste aqui a primeira solução que você trouxe e me retornou o seguindo problema: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer com um compreensão de lista assim:

```
nova_lista = [m_r_list[i] - m_r_list[i-1] for i in range(1:len(m_r_list))]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda!